# Moving items around in a python list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, append

This is the final product. IF anyone else has any tips to cut it up, please let me know! Thanks a lot for the help!

```
def triple_cut(deck):
    ''' (list of int) -> NoneType

    Modify deck by finding the first joker and putting all the cards above it
    to the bottom of deck, and all the cards below the second joker to the top
    of deck. 
    >>> deck = [2, 7, 3, 27, 11, 23, 28, 1, 6, 9, 13, 4]
    >>> triple_cut(deck) 
    >>> deck 
    [1, 6, 9, 13, 4, 27, 11, 23, 28, 2, 7, 3]
    '''     
    joker1 = deck.index(JOKER1)
    joker2 = deck.index(JOKER2)
    first = min(joker1, joker2)
    first_cards = []

    for cards in range(len(deck[:first])):
        cards = 0 
        pop = deck.pop(cards)
        first_cards.append(pop)

    joker1 = deck.index(JOKER1)
    joker2 = deck.index(JOKER2)
    second = max(joker1, joker2)    
    second_cards = []

    for cards in deck[second + 1:]:
        pop = deck.pop(deck.index(cards))
        second_cards.append(pop)

    second_cards.reverse()

    for card in second_cards: 
        deck.insert(0, card)

    deck.extend(first_cards)
```

raah I need to type more because my post is mostly code: please add more details sss ss

Comment: This would be a great example to learn some TDD btw. where you develop your code step by step and afterwards do your performance stuff.

Comment: I'll bet a unicorn dollar that you can do it nicely with [list slices](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

```
p = list('abcdefghijkl')
pivot = p.index('g')
q = p[pivot:] + p[:pivot]
```

List slicing is your friend.

Comment: Okay, so I've done this so far, but now my issue is that the deck is not being mutated after the function is passed:                        joker1 = deck.index(JOKER1)
    joker2 = deck.index(JOKER2)
    if joker1 < joker2: 
        first = joker1 
        second = joker2
    else: 
        first = joker2 
        second = joker1
        
    # Find the first joker and place it at the front of the deck. 
    q = deck[first:] + deck[:first]
    deck = q

Answer (score 0):

**answer to the second revision**

> when the function is finished, it won't mutate the deck.

The problem is that you didn't give the full code. I'm guessing it looks like this:

```
def triple_cut(deck)
    …
    deck = q
```

And according to your docstring you call it as

```
deck = […]
triple_cut(deck)
```

and have gotten confused that the assignment `deck = q` doesn't propagate out of `triple_cut()`. You can't modify the formal parameters of a method so the assignment remains local to triple_cut and **does not** affect the module level variable `deck`

The proper way to write this is

```
def triple_cut(cuttable)
    …
    return cuttable[first:] + cuttable[:first]

deck = […]
deck = triple_cut(deck)
```

where I changed the name of the argument to `cuttable` to for purposes of explanation. You could keep the argument name as `deck` but I wanted to show that when you thought you were assigning to deck you were really assigning to cuttable and that assignment wouldn't carry out of triple_cut().

Comment: Yes, this was the first thing I thought of. But for the assignment, this function returns NoneType so I can't do that. I wrote out code that seems really messy, but it works if you want to take a look.  Thanks a lot by the way!